# Case statement doesn't seem to be working

Tags: switch-statement, verilog

The value of `oV` should be the value on the right side in the `StateToCountSequence` that corresponds to the respective `iState` value on the left. However, `oV` only seems to be able to have the values 2 or 3, as shown the in capture below.

[image]

Does anyone know what I should do about this?

```
module CounterSkipReverse(iClk, iRst, iSkip, iRev, oState);
   input iClk, iRst, iSkip, iRev;
   //declare oState:
    output integer oState;
   //declare internal wires and reg types here:
    always @ (posedge iClk) begin
        if (iRst == 1)
            oState <= 0;
        else
            if (iSkip == 0 & iRev == 0) oState <= oState + 4'd1;
            else if (iSkip == 1 & iRev == 0) oState <= oState + 4'd5;
            else if (iSkip == 0 & iRev == 1) oState <= oState - 4'd1;
            else if (iSkip == 1 & iRev == 1) oState <= oState + 4'd9;
            if (oState < 0) oState <= oState + 4'd14;
            if (oState > 14) oState <= oState - 4'd14;
    end 
 
endmodule
 
module StateToCountSequence(iState, oV);
    //declare the input and output 
    input iState;
    output reg [3:0]oV;
  
    //declare any internal wire and reg types here.
    
    always @ (iState) begin
        case(iState)
            4'd0: oV = 4'd3;
            4'd1: oV = 4'd2;
            4'd2: oV = 4'd4;
            4'd3: oV = 4'd9;
            4'd4: oV = 4'd9;
            4'd5: oV = 4'd0;
            4'd6: oV = 4'd7;
            4'd7: oV = 4'd1;
            4'd8: oV = 4'd1;
            4'd9: oV = 4'd5;
            4'd10: oV = 4'd1;
            4'd11: oV = 4'd7;
            4'd12: oV = 4'd0;
            4'd13: oV = 4'd8;
            4'd14: oV = 4'd9;
        endcase
    end
  
    //Have you checked for inferred latches in this module?
endmodule 

module CompleteCounter(iClk, iRst, iSkip, iRev, oV, oState);
    input iClk, iRst, iSkip, iRev;
    output [3:0] oV;
    //declare oState next line
    output [3:0]oState;
    
    CounterSkipReverse cntr(.iClk(iClk), .iRst(iRst), .iSkip(iSkip), .iRev(iRev), .oState(oState));
    StateToCountSequence statemap(.iState(oState), .oV(oV));
endmodule

`timescale 1ns / 1ps
module AssignmentTestBench;
 
   //declare internal signals and instantiate module CompleteCounter.
    reg iClk, iRst, iSkip, iRev;
    wire [3:0]oState;
    wire [3:0]oV;
    
    initial begin
        iClk = 1'b1;
        iRst = 0;
        iSkip = 0;
        iRev = 0;
    end
    
    CompleteCounter counter(iClk, iRst, iSkip, iRev, oV, oState);
    
   //generate test sequences for all state transitions
    always begin
        #5 iClk = ~iClk;  //period 10 ns for clock
    end
    
    always begin  // control w input and reset
        #1;
        
        // iSkip = 0, iRev = 0
        #10 iRst = 1'b1;
        #10 iRst = 1'b0;
        #300;  // 30 clock cycles
        
        // iSkip = 1, iRev = 0
        #10 iRst = 1'b1;
        #10 iRst = 1'b0;
            iSkip = 1'b1;
        #80;
        
        // iSkip = 1, iRev = 1
        #10 iRst = 1'b1;
        #10 iRst = 1'b0;
            iRev = 1'b1;
        #40;
        
        // iSkip = 0, iRev = 1
        #10 iRst = 1'b1;
        #10 iRst = 1'b0;
            iSkip = 1'b0;
        #150;

        $display("Finished test");
        $finish;  // remove for modelsim
        $stop;
    end
  
endmodule
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The signal `iState` is a 1-bit signal in the `StateToCountSequence`, which means it can only take on the known values 0 and 1.  Thus, you can only set `oV` to 3 and 2.

Change:

```
input iState;
```

to:

```
input [3:0] iState;
```